# Iterating over documents with equals values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I have a collection of blog posts with "votes" field in mongo db:

```
> db.posts.find({}, {_id:0, votes: 1})
{ "votes" : 1 }
{ "votes" : 2 }
{ "votes" : 2 }
{ "votes" : 3 }
{ "votes" : 3 }
```

Than I have a web interface to display one post per page and controls (next, prev) to slide posts ordering by votes. I send request for next/prev post to server with current vote count and select new one. So I get next queries (one per http request)

```
> db.things.find({vote: {$gt: 0}}, {_id:0, votes:1}).limit(1) // current votes == 0
{ "votes" : 1 }
> db.things.find({vote: {$gt: 1}}, {_id:0, votes:1}).limit(1) // current votes == 1
{ "votes" : 2 }
> db.things.find({vote: {$gt: 2}}, {_id:0, votes:1}).limit(1) // current votes == 2
{ "votes" : 3 }
...
```

As you can see documents with equals "votes" where skipped. So I need some way to make documents unique and iterate over equals votes too (Votes field may be frequently updated and has many equals values per all documents).

Is there any way to solve this problem? Look like I need some sort of search index here. But  as I say criteria field  changes very frequently and I plan have a millions document. That means that index update will be very expensive operation and I want safe response of the system on updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what order the results come back in, you should sort them by `_id` and then use `{$gt: current_id}` to get the next one:

```
db.things.findOne({}, {votes: 1}).sort({_id: 1}) // _id == 0
db.things.findOne({_id: {$gt: 0}}, {votes: 1}).sort({_id: 1}) // _id == 1
db.things.findOne({_id: {$gt: 1}}, {votes: 1}).sort({_id: 1}) // _id == 2
...
```

If you need them ordered by `votes`, then you need to use `skip` instead:

```
db.things.findOne({}, {votes: 1}).sort({votes: 1})
db.things.findOne({}, {votes: 1}).sort({votes: 1}).skip(1)
db.things.findOne({}, {votes: 1}).sort({votes: 1}).skip(2)
...
```

But that gets progressively slower as you have to skip further and further into the result set.